# In Mac OS X, how can I get an accurate count of file descriptor usage?

Tags: macos, unix, lsof

On Linux, `ulimit -n` can be used to change or view the limit on the number of file descriptors for a process, and `lsof -p nnn | wc -l` seems to consistently report the actual file descriptor usage.

But on Mac OS X, `lsof -p nnn | wc -l` can return a number higher than the limit.  I suppose this means `lsof` is returning more than just file descriptors, but I can't tell what's what.

Bottom line: **How can I get an accurate count of file descriptor usage in Mac OS X?**

Comment: To start, don't pipe the output and see what it's actually listing. Then you'll have an idea of where those extra descriptors are coming from and what they are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

lsof can show a lot of things beyond just file descriptors, but most of what is likely inflating your count is the loaded frameworks and libraries for an application. You can look at the "FD" column to see if a line is a file descriptor--in which case it's a number, possibly followed by a letter indicating the mode--or something else (see the description of the FD column in the lsof man page for the full list).

If you just need a rough approximation adding a 'grep -v " txt "' before your wc will get you a lot closer to an accurate value. If you need an exact value, you probably need to put together a regex to feed the output through that filers precisely by the FD column.

Comment: `lsof -d "^txt"` will avoid the need of using grep.

Answer (score 51):

I came across the need for identifying this recently - the command I used to count up the total entries (so more than just file handles, but it's relative so therefore relevant in my opinion) is:

```
lsof | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

This gives something like the following output (your highest-used applications may be different!):

```
$lsof | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
1259 Google
 682 Code\x20H
 369 Spotify
 334 VLC
 322 cloudd
 303 corespotl
 278 com.apple
 273 UserEvent
 249 GitHub
 176 Slack\x20
```

I usually only need to see the top 10 entries, but you can manipulate `head` to show as many lines as you like (e.g., `head -n 40`).

Comment: you should `sort` before calling `uniq` to avoid duplicate entries : `lsof | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head`

Comment: Use `lsof -n` which doesn't try to resolve ips to domain names and goes much faster.

Comment: @deadbeef I tried both `lsof` and `lsof -n` and they were both 15 seconds, in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I modified anders' answer, now it only displays the opened fd numbers of a specific process:

```
FCOUNT=`lsof -p $1 | grep -v " txt " | wc -l`;echo "PID: $1 $FCOUNT" | sort -nk3
```

Example:

```
$ ./fd-count.sh 5926                                                                                                           
PID: 5926       97
```

Comment: If it matters to anyone, the count is off by one because `lsof -p $1` will print a header row in addition to the list of file descriptors.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for which process that had lots of file descriptors - so I guess something like

```
for pid in `ps aux | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}'`; do FCOUNT=`lsof -p $pid | grep -v " txt " | wc -l`; echo "PID: $pid $FCOUNT"; done | sort -nk3
```

Comment: `lsof: illegal process ID: PID`

Comment: @bithavoc, use

    for pid in `ps aux | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}'`; do FCOUNT=`lsof -p $pid | grep -v " txt " | wc -l`; echo "PID: $pid $FCOUNT"; done | sort -nk3

-- This will cut off the first row of ps output which contains column headers.

Comment: You should also add the `| tail -n +2` trick to the `lsof -p $pid | grep -v " txt " | wc -l` so that you don't end up counting the header row as a file descriptor.